# Xcode 4: view size target for Ipad

Tags: xcode, ipad, uitableview, size, xib

I created a new class in my project with a xib target for Ipad; in this file I put a tableview and I set its size, but I want change also size of view and I see that I can't change the x and y values, why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Delete the View from the xib and then add a new view and then you can change the height and width.

Comment: I understand, the problem is status top and bottom bar, these must be all at "none"

Answer (score 1):

Just Change the Property of the view.

**IN View Attribute just change the Status Bar value to unspecified.**

Thts it..!!